# Windows firewall settings keep resetting themselves after a few seconds

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

The Windows Firewall settings keep resetting themselves on my computer. Meaning no matter what settings I change, after about 5 seconds they switch back to whatever they were. This includes disabling the firewall (it re-enables itself) and adding rules. I thought maybe its something on the network, but even if I disable my wi-fi this keeps happening. Anyone have any suggestions? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have any Anti-Virus software running?

Comment: @duDE it looks like I have 'Trend Micro Security Agent' running.

Comment: Take a look: https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1055458-windows-firewall-settings-changed-after-installing-deep-security-agent-dsa "By default, DSA installation will disable Windows Firewall."